# WP Custom search form with custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to search on a post type taking into account a custom field.

When I perform the search by removing **meta_query** and I search by title it works, but as soon as I try to add **meta_query** , I have a blank page as a result.

What would be the cause of this problem?
I already looked at all the other forums on Stack, but none had the solution to my problem.

```
@php
 $searchTerm = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '';
 $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
@endphp

//My custom search form
<form role="search" method="GET" id="searchform" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="search">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Mot-clé" class="search__input">
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Rechercher" class="search__btn" />
</form>

// My query
@query([
 'post_type' => 'article',
 'posts_per_page' => 12,
 'paged' => $paged,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'orderby' => 'menu_order',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 's' => $searchTerm,
 'tax_query' => [
   [
    'taxonomy' => 'type',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'jurisprudence',
    ],
   ],
   'meta_query' => [
     [
      'key' => 'article-key',
      'value' => $searchTerm,
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
      ],
     ],
   ])
```

Comment: `'s' => $searchTerm,` still searches the title, and I don't know if that is just an OR relation with the meta query, or whether _both_ title and your custom key would now need to contain the search term ...?

Comment: I removed s=>$searchTerm , now it works with keyword search. But, is it not possible to do both? with the title and a custom field?

Comment: Don't know if there is any way to accomplish that simply via WP_Query configuration parameters. You might need to use one of the filters that can be used to manipulate the generated SQL code, and switch an `AND` to an `OR` somewhere - or it might need even more structural changes, depends on what the generated SQL actually looks like.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this gets a little ugly, see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178492/12496